# How make sure a Field implements an interface at compile time

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am building a java class to be used as a generic comparator based on the sample shown on [Generic Comparator](http://www.myjeeva.com/2012/04/generic-comparator-in-java/). The constructor I am building for the comparator is as follows:

```
public GenericComparator(java.lang.reflect.Field sortField, boolean ascending){
        ....   }
```

While the above constructor allows me to get the sort field, there is no way for the compiler to know if the field is implementing `Comparable` interface and a developer calling the constructor may pass a field that doesn't implement the `Comparable`interface.

I am wondering if there is a way to make this a compile time error and not handle it at Run time with the use of instanceof check to make sure the field has implemented the interface.

A similar implementation found in the `Collections.sort(...)` Type declaration.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Comparable.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
```

does it at runtime, but there's no way at all to make this a compile-time error.  Fields don't (and can't, really) carry their type information at compile time -- they're runtime objects, and can be chosen at runtime.  For example, if you had

```
random.nextBoolean() ? Foo.class.getField("bar") : Foo.class.getField("baz")
```

then no compiler, no matter how smart, could tell at compile time what type the resulting field would have.